check valve vs anti syphon valve
i want to take the outdoor hose bibs off an old pump/tank system  and connect them to the house city water line but i have a drain line going to the back garage that i use to drain that line for winter and putting those hose bib type anti syphon's will not work as it is under ground.
so installing a anti syphon is rather costly so i'm wondering if a check valve will do the same job?  i can install that next to the city line that i have good access to for tapping and running over to the pumps main line going to the outdoor hose bibs. this system is not used for sprinkling as that is a seperate system by itself

That's clear as mud. Perhaps you could [edit] in a diagram?

What creates the need for backflow prevention?  Are all hose bibs required to have it in your location? Or are you feeding an irrigation system or doing something that requires it?

Normally the protection of the city water system from whatever you have connected is non-negotiable and at the level of protection they require, with the devices they require, not whatever you consider to be a home-brew equivalent.
The fines when they catch you doing something they don't approve of are huge...so you won't be saving any money in the long run by doing it wrong. You'll have the expense of doing it wrong, then the expense of doing it right and a hefty fine for having done it wrong.
